# talking to components child to parent and parent to child vue.js

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

I am coming from an angular mindset and now I am trying to learn vue.js. I am using webpack and I have the following three `.vue` classes.
`CounterDisplay.vue`, IncrementButton.vue`, and`App.vue`. I want to increment  the`count`variable but all it does is`console.log`how many times I pressed the button. I am trying to figure out how child to parent and parent to child work in vue. Then I need to figure out the correct pattern to use vue in a very large application. In angular you have a`module`and in there you put your components and services etc. How does`vue` do this?

**CounterDisplay.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="#counterDisplay">
    {{count}}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        count: 0
      }
    }
  }
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

**IncrementButton.vue**

```
<template>
    <button @click.prevent="active">+1</button>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
      methods: {
        active () {
          console.log('+1 Pressed')
        }
      }
    }
</script>

<style scoped></style>
```

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <h3>Increment:</h3>
    <increment></increment>
    <h3>Counter:</h3>
    <counter></counter>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import Counter from './components/CounterDisplay.vue'
  import Increment from './components/IncrementButton.vue'
  export default {
    components: {
      Counter,
      Increment
    }
  }
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

This is the output:

[image]

Comment: so what is the problem?

Comment: @samayo I updated my question, sorry. I added one more quesion too, I know I should not ask more than one but it is related to my question to a degree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said:

> . I am trying to figure out how child to parent and parent to child work

This is how you do it:

1. Set up a `counter` data property in **App.vue**
2. Emit an event using `vm.$emit()` in **IncrementButton.vue** component on every button click
3. Set up an event listener on this component `increment` and execute the method whenever this event is emitted
4. In the event call back method increase the counter by 1
5. Send the counter property as a prop to ****CounterDisplay.vue**

*App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <h3>Increment:</h3>
    <increment @btn-clicked="increaseCounter"></increment>
    <h3>Counter:</h3>
    <counter :counter="counter"></counter>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import Counter from './components/CounterDisplay.vue'
  import Increment from './components/IncrementButton.vue'
  export default {
      data(){
          counter:0
      },
    components: {
      Counter,
      Increment
    },
    methods:{
        increaseCounter(){
            this.counter ++;
        }
    }
  }
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

**IncrementButton.vue**

```
<template>
    <button @click.prevent="active">+1</button>
</template>

<script>
    import {EventBus} from './path/to/main.js'
    export default {
      methods: {
        active () {
          console.log('+1 Pressed')
          //emitting an event
          this.$emit('btn-clicked');
        }
      }
    }
</script>

<style scoped></style>
```

**CounterDisplay.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="#counterDisplay">
    {{counter}}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
      props:['counter'],
    data () {
      return {
      }
    },
  }
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

**--------------------**

Since the two components are non parent-child components the simple scenario would be using an [EventBus](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Non-Parent-Child-Communication)

Declare an EventBus which is nothing more than an empty Vue instance in your main.js file

```
export const EventBus = new Vue();
```

The only focus of this empty vue instance is to listen and respond to events from components

**IncrementButton.vue**

```
<template>
    <button @click.prevent="active">+1</button>
</template>

<script>
    import {EventBus} from './path/to/main.js'
    export default {
      methods: {
        active () {
          console.log('+1 Pressed')
          //emitting an event
          //Syntax is EventBus.$emit('event-name', eventData);
          EventBus.$emit('btn-clicked', 1);
        }
      }
    }
</script>

<style scoped></style>
```

Now setup an listener for `btn-clicked` event in created hook of 8*CounterDisplay.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="#counterDisplay">
    {{count}}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
    import {EventBus} from './path/to/main.js'
  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        count: 0
      }
    },
    created(){
        EventBus.$on('btn-clicked', (eventData) => {
            this.count = this.count + eventData;
        });
    }
  }
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

Note: As you want to know the correct pattern for a large app, I would recommend using [vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/intro.html)